# Adding Date parameters to reports TSQL

Tags: sql, visual-studio, t-sql, reporting-services

Quick one today.

In ssrs if I want to enter a default date in report parameters of say a week ago I enter.

```
  =DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -7, Today())
```

Which will give me 07/03/2012

Now what do I enter to add time to the function say I want it like this:

01/03/2012 10:07:06

Thanks you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`=DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -7, Now)`